# VS2012 Build page has not effect on debug or release settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to build a project for release in VS2012.
I got to Properties->Build and change the configuration to Release, set my platform (x86) and rebuild expecting the code to be optimized and put in the x86/Release folder.
The code is placed in the same Debug folder and I can still do real-time debugging which means in is not release.

If I go to the Configuration Manager I can change the Active solution configuration to Debug or Release and that works, but once again regardless of how the build page is configured.

I want to the Build page to control how the project is build not the configuration manager as it did in VS 2008 and 2010.

All online resources talk about using the build tab for control and the configuration manager for adding new Configurations, but nothing about requiring the configuration manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Build page doesn't control which configuration you're building, it only controls what the settings are for each configuration.

To change the active Configuration, you need to use the Configuration Manager or the Solution Configurations dropdown in the toolbar.

Comment: Has it always been like this? I have used the build tab before, but I wonder if I was simply always changing the same configuration so it always worked?

Comment: I don't believe the Build page (or in older versions, the Project Properties dialog) has ever changed the active configuration.